# My Android projector is missing a status bar, how do I get it back?

Tags: notification-bar

So I have this Android Projector I bought from ebay, it's one of those cheap Android pico projectors that come with some Chinese ROMs. The issue I have with it is that it's really restrictive. The custom Android ROM they have pre-installed on this projector wants to pretend it's not Android.

It tries to hide elements of typical Android as much as it can, it has a launcher that I have to set as my default launcher because it's the only way of accessing the settings of the projector and the source (i.e. switching to HDMI, etc.) and one thing that really bugs me is that it feels like they've taken the stock android settings app and stripped loads of settings from it.

It bugs me that the status bar is missing because I like to see what time it is, how much battery/wifi I have etc without having to sluggishly tap the "back" button until I reach the home screen (the launcher has a few icons that tell me the battery/wifi status and time.

I've tried installing a status bar app, but they ask for permissions, one permission they ask is "accessibility service" but the ability to enable accessibility services has been stripped entirely from the settings app (you can't access "accessibility services" at all) and enabling permissions using ADB for apps does absolutely nothing.

I don't want to flash a custom ROM, because then I lose the ability to use HDMI and that sucks. If I can't do it, then fair enough, but I'd at least like to see a status bar in some way. I've tried messing around with "SettingsEditor" and attempting to grant permissions with ADB, but I've run out of options.

The name of the device according to the ADB shell is "rk3128_box" and that's about as much information as I have on the ROM, it uses a launcher called "com.hotack.hotackcommlauncher" which has the same name as it's package name. That's all the info I have, if there's no solutions, that's no problem, but I was just wondering if maybe there's some solution. Thanks .

Comment: When using a different launcher was the status bar visible as you want it?

Comment: @Robert Nope that doesn't fix anything

Comment: Then you would have to modify the ROM itself. Not sure what may have been changed to hide the status bar. Sorry but I can't help you on that.